# What's the best way to remove items from an ordered collection?

Tags: c#, collections, html-lists

I have a list of items to remove from an ordered collection in C#.

what's the best way in going about this?

If I remove an item in the middle, the index changes but what If I want to remove multiple items?

Comment: Is your list of items to delete sorted?

Answer (score 4):

To avoid index changes, start at the end and go backwards to index 0.

Something along these lines:

```
for(int i = myList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i++) 
{
    if(NeedToDelete(myList[i]))
    {
        myList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add to this -- I think she means start from the last item you want to remove, and go upwards.

Comment: @BeemerGuy: I added a code sample to illustrate what I meant.

Comment: oh ok, I thought the OP knew the indecies ahead of time.

Comment: @BeemerGuy: yeah, it's a bit hard to tell from the question. I'm not sure if my interpretation is right either.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of the collection?  If it inherits from [ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx), you can just run a loop over the list of items to remove, then call the `.Remove()` method on the collection.

For Example:

```
object[] itemsToDelete = GetObjectsToDeleteFromSomewhere();
ICollection<object> orderedCollection = GetCollectionFromSomewhere();

foreach (object item in itemsToDelete)
{
    orderedCollection.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Only if you go by index starting at the end or save indices to be removed into an array or something. Doing a foreach over a collection and calling Remove() on it at the same time will raise an exception.

Comment: See my example.  If you are looping over another a array, and want to remove the items from a different collection, this will work fine.  That's how I read the question anyways.  Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @Anna -- he is not removing from the collection he is iterating, so that exception won't happen here.  Here's iterating the items to delete.

Comment: This is very inefficient since you are pretty much making a copy of the items.

Comment: @BeemerGuy: My comment was written before the example went up. @Kyle: Ah, makes sense. I thought you meant looping over the original collection. I misread.

Comment: @LB that just depends on what is in the collection. If they are reference types he only copies references, not the entire object.

Answer (score 1):

If the collection is a `List<T>` you can also use the [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method:

```
list.RemoveAll(x => otherlist.Contains(x));
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not an IList but an ICollection

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the list of items to delete is relatively short, you can first sort the target list. Than traverse the source list and keep an index in the target list which corresponds to the item which you deleted.

Supposed that the source list is `haystack` and list of items to delete is `needle`:

```
needle.Sort(); // not needed if it's known that `needle` is sorted
// haystack is known to be sorted
haystackIdx = 0;
needleIdx = 0;
while (needleIdx < needle.Count && haystackIdx < haystack.Count)
{
    if (haystack[haystackIdx] < needle[needleIdx])
        haystackIdx++;
    else if (haystack[haystackIdx] > needle[needleIdx])
        needleIdx++;
    else
        haystack.RemoveAt(haystackIdx);
}
```

This way you have only 1 traversal of both `haystack` and `needle`, plus the time of sorting the `needle`, provided the deletion is `O(1)` (which is often the case for linked lists and the collections like that). If the collection is a `List<...>`, deletion will need `O(collection size)` because of data shifts, so you'd better start from the end of both collections and move to the beginning:

```
needle.Sort(); // not needed if it's known that `needle` is sorted
// haystack is known to be sorted
haystackIdx = haystack.Count - 1;
needleIdx = needle.Count - 1;
while (needleIdx >= 0 && haystackIdx >= 0)
{
    if (haystack[haystackIdx] > needle[needleIdx])
        haystackIdx--;
    else if (haystack[haystackIdx] < needle[needleIdx])
        needleIdx--;
    else
        haystack.RemoveAt(haystackIdx--);
}
```